# Count Dynamic Fields in Cocoon Gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I'm a little bit stuck with counting in the forms produced by cocoon gem. Can someone help me?

I need to put a numbering in a box, like "Add Party#1 Add Party#2 Add Party#3"

My Button:

```
<%= link_to_add_association '+ Add Party', f, :case_parties, :partial => 'client_party_fields', :class => 'btn btn-inverse', :id => 'btn_client_add_party', :count => 1 %>
```

When I clicked that, it renders

```
<div class="box"> 
 <div>Party # some number </div> 
  <div class="content> 
   <input class="form-control" id="test" name="test[case_number]" type="text"> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Please put the code in the question, that is more readable :) You can just edit your question.

Comment: Hi Nathan. :) Please help me. Your the author of cocoon right? :D